# Redirect from .net to .nl [.htaccess]

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have moved my website from .net to .nl, all url's are exactly the same. Is there a simple code that I can use to redirect all visitors that go to .net to .nl?

Also, is there a way to test this for only my IP address?

Comment: What did you try? This is a basic redirect.

Comment: Nothing really. Not sure what to look for.

Comment: I know how to redirect an URL, but in this case I need to redirect *everything*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect+old+domain+new+domain

Comment: Again, that is a very common redirect. Just Search. All you're doing is redirecting from old domain to new one

Comment: If you try a redirect rule and it doesn't work out edit your post accordingly and leave a comment.